# Where can I find the source code for the .Net Core string extension method "Substring"?

Tags: c#

As far as I know Microsoft have made .Net Core open source located at https://github.com/dotnet/runtime.

Since I want to look at the source code for the `string` extension method "Substring" and its overloads I went over there and used Github's search functionality to look for it but had no success. I then downloaded the entire repo and ran a local windows search but couldn't find anything, again, even after looking through the folders and files. Suffice it to say I am a huge novice at navigating and understanding how code is structured.

So where can I find the source code for the "Substring" method and its overloads?

Comment: I don't think that's an extension method, is it? `Substring` is a method of the `String` class itself: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,8124961f027d9ac9

Comment: BTW, my link is the "old school" code. The git repo is located at: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource.  From there go to `mscorlib`, then `System`, then `String.cs`. But I prefer https://referencesource.microsoft.com for searchability

Comment: The premise of this question seems flawed because, as @RufusL pointed out, `string.Substring()` is not an extension method, which may or may not have affected your ability to find it.  If you are somehow working with a `Substring()` extension method that operates on `string` instances, you'll need to specify which class/assembly defines it (and, of course, the code for that — not the runtime — would be the place to start looking).

Comment: @RufusL, thanks, but that is the .Net Framework version, while I am asking about the .Net Core version.

Comment: @BACON, you are correct it's very likely I have confused the term "extension method". The problem is I can't find any "Substring" anywhere in the .Net Core source code.

Answer (score 7):

You can find it here [string.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/string.cs) for framework

The fundamental implementation is as such

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
unsafe string InternalSubString(int startIndex, int length) 
{
    Contract.Assert( startIndex >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length, "StartIndex is out of range!");
    Contract.Assert( length >= 0 && startIndex <= this.Length - length, "length is out of range!");            
        
    String result = FastAllocateString(length);

    fixed(char* dest = &result.m_firstChar)
        fixed(char* src = &this.m_firstChar) {
            wstrcpy(dest, src + startIndex, length);
        }

    return result;
}
```

Basically it just allocates what it needs, and pointer copies using `wstrcpy` which in turn uses `memcpy`, and that just iterates over pointers with a loop

```
memcpy (void *dest, const void *src, size_t len)
{
  char *d = dest;
  const char *s = src;
  while (len--)
    *d++ = *s++;
  return dest;
}
```

**Update**

Note the *.Net Core* uses a different *codebase* for this method which can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L1742)

[`SubString`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L1707)  calls [`InternalSubString`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L1742) calls [`Buffer.Memmove`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/buffer.cs) which has been heavily optimized for certain situations and environments

```
internal unsafe static void Memmove(byte* dest, byte* src, nuint len)
{
#if AMD64 || (BIT32 && !ARM)
   const nuint CopyThreshold = 2048;
#elif ARM64
#if PLATFORM_WINDOWS
   // 

   const nuint CopyThreshold = 2048;
#else // PLATFORM_WINDOWS
   // Managed code is currently faster than glibc unoptimized memmove
   // 

   const nuint CopyThreshold = UInt64.MaxValue;
#endif // PLATFORM_WINDOWS
#else
   const nuint CopyThreshold = 512;
#endif // AMD64 || (BIT32 && !ARM)

   // P/Invoke into the native version when the buffers are overlapping.

   if (((nuint)dest - (nuint)src < len) || ((nuint)src - (nuint)dest < len)) goto PInvoke;

   byte* srcEnd = src + len;
   byte* destEnd = dest + len;

   if (len <= 16) goto MCPY02;
   if (len > 64) goto MCPY05;

   MCPY00:
   // Copy bytes which are multiples of 16 and leave the remainder for MCPY01 to handle.
   Contract.Assert(len > 16 && len <= 64);
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block16*)dest = *(Block16*)src;                   // [0,16]
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)dest = *(long*)src;
   *(long*)(dest + 8) = *(long*)(src + 8);             // [0,16]
#else
   *(int*)dest = *(int*)src;
   *(int*)(dest + 4) = *(int*)(src + 4);
   *(int*)(dest + 8) = *(int*)(src + 8);
   *(int*)(dest + 12) = *(int*)(src + 12);             // [0,16]
#endif
   if (len <= 32) goto MCPY01;
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block16*)(dest + 16) = *(Block16*)(src + 16);     // [0,32]
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)(dest + 16) = *(long*)(src + 16);
   *(long*)(dest + 24) = *(long*)(src + 24);           // [0,32]
#else
   *(int*)(dest + 16) = *(int*)(src + 16);
   *(int*)(dest + 20) = *(int*)(src + 20);
   *(int*)(dest + 24) = *(int*)(src + 24);
   *(int*)(dest + 28) = *(int*)(src + 28);             // [0,32]
#endif
   if (len <= 48) goto MCPY01;
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block16*)(dest + 32) = *(Block16*)(src + 32);     // [0,48]
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)(dest + 32) = *(long*)(src + 32);
   *(long*)(dest + 40) = *(long*)(src + 40);           // [0,48]
#else
   *(int*)(dest + 32) = *(int*)(src + 32);
   *(int*)(dest + 36) = *(int*)(src + 36);
   *(int*)(dest + 40) = *(int*)(src + 40);
   *(int*)(dest + 44) = *(int*)(src + 44);             // [0,48]
#endif

   MCPY01:
   // Unconditionally copy the last 16 bytes using destEnd and srcEnd and return.
   Contract.Assert(len > 16 && len <= 64);
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block16*)(destEnd - 16) = *(Block16*)(srcEnd - 16);
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)(destEnd - 16) = *(long*)(srcEnd - 16);
   *(long*)(destEnd - 8) = *(long*)(srcEnd - 8);
#else
   *(int*)(destEnd - 16) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 16);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 12) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 12);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 8) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 8);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 4) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 4);
#endif
   return;

   MCPY02:
   // Copy the first 8 bytes and then unconditionally copy the last 8 bytes and return.
   if ((len & 24) == 0) goto MCPY03;
   Contract.Assert(len >= 8 && len <= 16);
#if BIT64
   *(long*)dest = *(long*)src;
   *(long*)(destEnd - 8) = *(long*)(srcEnd - 8);
#else
   *(int*)dest = *(int*)src;
   *(int*)(dest + 4) = *(int*)(src + 4);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 8) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 8);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 4) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 4);
#endif
   return;

   MCPY03:
   // Copy the first 4 bytes and then unconditionally copy the last 4 bytes and return.
   if ((len & 4) == 0) goto MCPY04;
   Contract.Assert(len >= 4 && len < 8);
   *(int*)dest = *(int*)src;
   *(int*)(destEnd - 4) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 4);
   return;

   MCPY04:
   // Copy the first byte. For pending bytes, do an unconditionally copy of the last 2 bytes and return.
   Contract.Assert(len < 4);
   if (len == 0) return;
   *dest = *src;
   if ((len & 2) == 0) return;
   *(short*)(destEnd - 2) = *(short*)(srcEnd - 2);
   return;

   MCPY05:
   // PInvoke to the native version when the copy length exceeds the threshold.
   if (len > CopyThreshold)
   {
       goto PInvoke;
   }
   // Copy 64-bytes at a time until the remainder is less than 64.
   // If remainder is greater than 16 bytes, then jump to MCPY00. Otherwise, unconditionally copy the last 16 bytes and return.
   Contract.Assert(len > 64 && len <= CopyThreshold);
   nuint n = len >> 6;

   MCPY06:
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block64*)dest = *(Block64*)src;
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)dest = *(long*)src;
   *(long*)(dest + 8) = *(long*)(src + 8);
   *(long*)(dest + 16) = *(long*)(src + 16);
   *(long*)(dest + 24) = *(long*)(src + 24);
   *(long*)(dest + 32) = *(long*)(src + 32);
   *(long*)(dest + 40) = *(long*)(src + 40);
   *(long*)(dest + 48) = *(long*)(src + 48);
   *(long*)(dest + 56) = *(long*)(src + 56);
#else
   *(int*)dest = *(int*)src;
   *(int*)(dest + 4) = *(int*)(src + 4);
   *(int*)(dest + 8) = *(int*)(src + 8);
   *(int*)(dest + 12) = *(int*)(src + 12);
   *(int*)(dest + 16) = *(int*)(src + 16);
   *(int*)(dest + 20) = *(int*)(src + 20);
   *(int*)(dest + 24) = *(int*)(src + 24);
   *(int*)(dest + 28) = *(int*)(src + 28);
   *(int*)(dest + 32) = *(int*)(src + 32);
   *(int*)(dest + 36) = *(int*)(src + 36);
   *(int*)(dest + 40) = *(int*)(src + 40);
   *(int*)(dest + 44) = *(int*)(src + 44);
   *(int*)(dest + 48) = *(int*)(src + 48);
   *(int*)(dest + 52) = *(int*)(src + 52);
   *(int*)(dest + 56) = *(int*)(src + 56);
   *(int*)(dest + 60) = *(int*)(src + 60);
#endif
   dest += 64;
   src += 64;
   n--;
   if (n != 0) goto MCPY06;

   len %= 64;
   if (len > 16) goto MCPY00;
#if HAS_CUSTOM_BLOCKS
   *(Block16*)(destEnd - 16) = *(Block16*)(srcEnd - 16);
#elif BIT64
   *(long*)(destEnd - 16) = *(long*)(srcEnd - 16);
   *(long*)(destEnd - 8) = *(long*)(srcEnd - 8);
#else
   *(int*)(destEnd - 16) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 16);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 12) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 12);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 8) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 8);
   *(int*)(destEnd - 4) = *(int*)(srcEnd - 4);
#endif
   return;

   PInvoke:
   _Memmove(dest, src, len);
}
```

Comment: Or https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs#L1742 which uses `Buffer.Memmove` ?

Comment: Since I'm only interested in the .Net Core version one, as stated in the question, I don't understand what is called and where when I do `"test".Substring(4)`? Where is the method definition for "Substring"?